# Visual Studio - Code Cleanup Doesn't Apply Naming Preferences

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-cleanup, editorconfig

I have an `.editorconfig` file that has my naming preferences in it. When I run code cleanup, it automatically formats seemingly all of my other preferences besides the naming. When I hover over a variable that is violating a naming preference it tells me which one it is violating and I can right click to change it to the correct format, but this does not automatically happen when running code cleanup like the rest of my preferences.

Am I missing a VS setting to automatically apply naming preferences from an `.editorconfig` when running code cleanup?

Example Preference Notification:

[image]

Editor Config naming preference:

```
# Naming rules

dotnet_naming_rule.private_or_internal_field_should_be_underscore_prefixed_camel_case.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.private_or_internal_field_should_be_underscore_prefixed_camel_case.symbols = private_or_internal_field
dotnet_naming_rule.private_or_internal_field_should_be_underscore_prefixed_camel_case.style = underscore_prefixed_camel_case


# Symbol specifications

dotnet_naming_symbols.class.applicable_kinds = class
dotnet_naming_symbols.class.applicable_accessibilities = public, internal, private, protected, protected_internal, private_protected
dotnet_naming_symbols.class.required_modifiers = 

dotnet_naming_symbols.interface.applicable_kinds = interface
dotnet_naming_symbols.interface.applicable_accessibilities = public, internal, private, protected, protected_internal, private_protected
dotnet_naming_symbols.interface.required_modifiers = 

dotnet_naming_symbols.method.applicable_kinds = method
dotnet_naming_symbols.method.applicable_accessibilities = *
dotnet_naming_symbols.method.required_modifiers = 

dotnet_naming_symbols.property.applicable_kinds = property
dotnet_naming_symbols.property.applicable_accessibilities = public, internal, private, protected, protected_internal, private_protected
dotnet_naming_symbols.property.required_modifiers = 

dotnet_naming_symbols.public_or_protected_field.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.public_or_protected_field.applicable_accessibilities = public, protected
dotnet_naming_symbols.public_or_protected_field.required_modifiers = 

dotnet_naming_symbols.private_or_internal_field.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_or_internal_field.applicable_accessibilities = internal, private, private_protected
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_or_internal_field.required_modifiers = 

dotnet_naming_symbols.types.applicable_kinds = class, struct, interface, enum
dotnet_naming_symbols.types.applicable_accessibilities = public, internal, private, protected, protected_internal, private_protected
dotnet_naming_symbols.types.required_modifiers = 

dotnet_naming_symbols.non_field_members.applicable_kinds = property, event, method
dotnet_naming_symbols.non_field_members.applicable_accessibilities = public, internal, private, protected, protected_internal, private_protected
dotnet_naming_symbols.non_field_members.required_modifiers = 

dotnet_naming_symbols.local_method_variable.applicable_kinds = field, parameter
dotnet_naming_symbols.local_method_variable.applicable_accessibilities = local
dotnet_naming_symbols.local_method_variable.required_modifiers = 

dotnet_naming_symbols.private_const_variable.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_const_variable.applicable_accessibilities = private
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_const_variable.required_modifiers = const

dotnet_naming_symbols.local_const_variable.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.local_const_variable.applicable_accessibilities = local
dotnet_naming_symbols.local_const_variable.required_modifiers = const

# Naming styles

dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.required_prefix = 
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.required_suffix = 
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.word_separator = 
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.capitalization = pascal_case

dotnet_naming_style.begins_with_i.required_prefix = I
dotnet_naming_style.begins_with_i.required_suffix = 
dotnet_naming_style.begins_with_i.word_separator = 
dotnet_naming_style.begins_with_i.capitalization = pascal_case

dotnet_naming_style.underscore_prefixed_camel_case.required_prefix = _
dotnet_naming_style.underscore_prefixed_camel_case.required_suffix = 
dotnet_naming_style.underscore_prefixed_camel_case.word_separator = 
dotnet_naming_style.underscore_prefixed_camel_case.capitalization = camel_case
```

Comment: For me only right-clicking the solution -> Analyze and Code Cleanup -> Run Code Cleanup seems to work. Which VS version are you using? Oh, and I had to put ```root = true``` at the first line of the ```.editorconfig``` for it to work. Not sure if that's related.

Comment: @imsmn - using VS 2019 v16.9.5. The code cleanup itself runs, and applies all my preferences except the naming ones. I do also have the `root = true`.

Comment: @DeveloperGuy Interesting, I'm using v16.8.5. Could you post your whole ```.editorconfig``` and point out an example? I'll see if it works with my version.

Comment: @imsmn yup, I've updated my question with the naming preference portion of my `.editorconfig` and included a screenshot of an example. As you can see, VS calls out that the naming rule is violated, however when I run code cleanup it does not automatically update it.

Comment: @DeveloperGuy Doesn't work with my version either. The 'Configure Code Cleanup' dialog provides way less fixes, too. Seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 2):

For now, the kind of fixers that can be run via Code Cleanup is limited to a predefined set, which doesn't include one to handle the `IDE1006` case.

[image]

There's an open issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/40263) about having more control over this.

From Kendra Havens, a product manager on the Visual Studio team:

> **Currently fixers included in a code cleanup profile are added by the
> product team on a case-by-case basis. Only then can they be included
> by users.** Since all fixers, (including 3rd party fixers) can be
> specified in EditorConfig it'd be natural to be able to include any of
> those in a code cleanup profile.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is some issue with how you are configuring the your naming styles.

This is a complete guide for how to Configure Naming Styles and Rules in Visual Studio and also at the solution/project level with an .editorconfig file.

**Link** : https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2021/02/06/configure-naming-styles-and-rules-in-visual-studio-and-also-at-the-solution-project-level-with-an-editorconfig-file/

The important thing to note is that:

**"solution or a project can override these rules, so that everyone who works on the solution/project is using the same rules, no matter what they have configured in Visual Studio"**.

As you can see a sample example in this pic:
[image]